# Powershell to compare groupmembership of input users with a particular group

Tags: powershell

I have a list of users , I want to check if the input list of users are member of a particular group, Sorry to ask such basic question , as I am beginner in powershell.

http://pastebin.com/YBUw2xNj

I have only user_id in the list , I want to compare each user id with one group , whether user is a member of that one group or not. Like say user,user2,user3 is a member of testgroup.

For example -

user1     testgroup
user2     testgroup
user3     testgroup

Regards
Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Csv looks like this:

```
username, groupname
a12358, european administrators
m235813, european users
```

this one-liner will return the users that are member of the corresponding group:

```
import-csv usergroup.csv | foreach-object {get-qaduser $_.username -memberof $_.groupname}
```

Comment: Sorry , My question was not clear ...... I have only user_id in the list , I want to compare each user id with one group , whether user is a member of that one group or not. Like say user,user2,user3 is a member of testgroup.

Comment: Something like this: `"user","user2","user3" | get-qaduser -memberof testgroup`?

Comment: import-csv userid.csv | foreach-object {get-qaduser $_.username -memberof $_.testgroup} , I want to compare user_id from csv with a group called testgroup whether user is a member of testgroup

Comment: Hi Jon , thanks from the reply , I have achieved what I was looking. I put group name in csv file and compare . thanks again for the help.